# How to find the sum of Beatty sequence of floor(e)+floor(2*e)+floor(3*e)......

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

How to find the sum of Beatty sequence of
$\lfloor e \rfloor+\lfloor 2e\rfloor+\lfloor 3e \rfloor\dots$ and so on?

Can it be reduced to recursion?

Comment: Well, since $e > 0$, I doubt that it even converges.